# Closing a View whenever it is opened/activated

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to close a view from my plugin. The requirement is as follows.

1. User will select Menu1 (lets say start) provided by my plugin.
2. Now if the user tries to select a particular view, then it should not be allowed until the user selects another Menu, lets say stop.

I searched in google and found out that, I can use activePage.hideView() method for closing the view. As I have no option for removing a view completely, I have created a PartListener and in partActivated() method, I am calling the hideview method.

By following this approach, the view gets closed but with the Runtime Exception which says "Preventing the recursive activation of org.eclipse.ui.ProjectExplorer before activation of the view ... xyz ...."( that I was closing).

Kindly help me in taking the proper approach for closing a view whenever it is opened/activated by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try delaying the `hideView` call by using `Display.asyncExec`. In your `partActivated` method use:

```java
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable()
 {
   @Override
   public void run()
   {
      ... call hideView here
   }
 });
```

The `asyncExec` `Runnable` will not be run until after the `partActivated` code has run which should stop the recursive activation warning.

Comment: Thank you very much @greg-449 for the immediate reply. I checked it on a sample code and it is working perfectly fine. Tomorrow I will check it with my actual project.  Once again thank you very much.